# Maven assembly : add different version of the same artifact

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I create my application archive with the maven assembly plugin. 
All the dependency present in my pom are included without any problem.

Now I need to include two or more version of the same artifact.

If in my pom I put

```
<dependencies>
        [...]
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>db.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Of source the dependenvcy resolver remove the old version and only the 1.1.0 is packaged in the archive

I try to include the jar by using assembly xml descriptor file. And I didn't find any solution.

A possible solution will be to manually put all the needed model.jar inside a folder and tell the assembly to copy it in the archive. But I'm looking for a more configurable solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: No worries about the need/conflict/.. anything else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution by using maven-dependency-plugin to copy resolved pom dependencies and additional jar.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-model</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>my.test.pkg</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
                    <classifier>server</classifier>
                    <version>1.0.3</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>my.test.pkg</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-model</artifactId>
                    <classifier>server</classifier>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Now I just have to add the following lines in my assembly xml

```
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>false</filtered>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
        <fileMode>0600</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: may ask if you do this, when both versions are loaded to jvm, shouldn't there be a conflict?

Comment: I had exact same requirement and your solution saved time. @lucky_start_izumi - it does in most cases, but in my case it is for an application which uses YAJSW which needed an older library and my application needed a newer one. In my scenario, they run on different classpaths.

Comment: @lucky_start_izumi um no? Any reasonably designed plugin architecture uses isolation-based classloader architectures. By design, the old class loaded by classloader A and utilized by C can never and will never conflict by classloader B loading the newer implementation which gets utilized in isolation by D. This is classloader-utilization-101. And is often required when youre using two independent externally created plugins, one of which is using an older version of the same dependency that some other plugin utilizes. Your app design is very poor if it cant anticipate this common scenario

Answer (score 12):

Maven assumes it doesn't make any sense to have more than one version of a module at once.  It assumes that a newer version replaces the older version.  If it doesn't it is not the same module.  I suggest you give the newer module a different name and make sure it has different packages to avoid choising a random module.

In general Maven tried to encourage good application design and deliberately makes it difficult to do things it has determined to be a bad idea.

Comment: This jar have different classes with different package name. They will be loaded by using ServiceLoader to build different xml model to keep back compatibility. I think in my case it's not a bad practice. I will try to see if it's possible and not boring to change name on every release.

Comment: I would vouch for the name change two, if you're going to use both.

Comment: Of course yes ! Everything is different only the groupeid and the artifactid are the same.

Comment: We need to ship multiple different versions of a database driver in our distribution, so that the our application can support different legacy and current versions of the database.  They are all the same groupId:artifactId but different versions.  We will of course package them in separate subdirs in our .zip.  But maven should not assume so much, without thinking through every use-case.

Comment: The reason maven was created was that there are so many details which you need to specify for a Java build that it's not manageable to do everything by hand - which is what ant was asking of you. Hence, maven _always_ assumes, by design. Only, it also (almost) always has a way to change every possible default it assumes.

Answer (score 1):

Another ugly solution might be to use WAR file overlays, exploiting the fact that this mechanism pays no attention to the versions of component JAR files when applying the overlays.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, different versions means replacing the older one. If we have to consume two different versions of a webservice for some business requirement. It is a good idea to generate the stubs in different packages and while adding to maven you can specify different them in `groupid`. This should work.