# Maven project depending on two versions of the same artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with two seperate modules that uses sqlline and another library(say OtherLib) that depends on jline. However on different versions.

## External Libraries

Module1 uses Sqlline depends on **jline 2.10**

Module2 uses OtherLib depends on **jline 0.9.94**

And the two versions are incompatible.
Therefore I have set the classpaths such that Module1 will search in *$HOME/lib/module1* folder first and Module2 in *$HOME/lib* folder first.

Is there a way to specify maven to download the artifact to a source directory first(say *../resources/lib*) and then copy it to package during packaging time in `assembly.xml`?

I know that for copying from source directory the following code can be used.

```
<fileSets>
   <fileSet> 
        <directory>../resources/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${HOME}/lib/module1</outputDirectory>
        <directoryMode>755</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>644</fileMode>
        <includes>
            <include>*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Also to get maven to download the dependency I can use (for Module2)

```
 <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>${HOME}/lib</outputDirectory>
        <directoryMode>755</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>644</fileMode>
        <includes>
            <include>jline:jline:jar:0.9.94</include>
        </includes>
    </dependencySet>
<dependencySets>
```

How can I make sure `jline:jline:jar:2.10` is downloaded to *../resources/lib* folder first?

Comment: Do the two different major versions use the same fully-qualified class names? If so, then you're in for trouble even with clever classloading.

Comment: @chrylis No luckily there are drastic changes among the two versions. So no conflicts discovered so far. Actually this is working fine when I manually add the jar to `../resources/lib` but doing this manually is unacceptable for this project.

Comment: If I understand well, your problem is at runtime, not compile time, right ? And you have a multi-module project, with no dependency between the 2 modules ? Are the modules jar-with-dependencies projects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314632/1925980) using **maven-dependency-plugin**

In **pom.xml**

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>copy-model</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>copy</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <artifactItems>
                   <artifactItem>
                       <groupId>jline</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
                       <version>2.10</version>
                       <type>jar</type>
                   </artifactItem>
                 <artifactItems>
                 <outputDirectory>../../resources/lib</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
     </plugin>
   <plugins>  
 <build>
```

And in **assembly.xml**

```
   <fileSet>
        <directory>../../resources/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${HOME}/lib/module1</outputDirectory>
        <directoryMode>755</directoryMode>
        <fileMode>644</fileMode>
        <includes>
            <include>jline-*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

`jline-0.9.94` is included in a `dependencySet` as any other dependency.
I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're absolutely sure, what you're doing, you can repackage one of the version using something like [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). But please be absolutely sure, what you're doing.

With [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) you could create a new Maven module, say `jline:jline_2_10:jar:1.0` and use `jline:jline:jar:2.10` as a dependency. The [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) would then package it in your `jline_2_10-1.0.jar`.

Since your new artifact has its own `groupId:artifactId` combination, there will be no conflicts with the other `jline:jline:jar:0.9.94` artifact, so you'll happily have both in the classpath.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But I'm not sure whether this will work because only jars used by my programs depends on jline and not my application directly. Anyway I'd post how I sorted this for anyone else having the same problem.