# I am Getting Maven compiler error while i am running Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, pom.xml

[image]

Could anyone please give me suggestion how can i solve this issue?

Maven Version : 4.0.0

maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1

[image]

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: Do you have a dependency for selenium set in your pom.xml?

Comment: Issue is fixed.. :) Thanks all of you guys for your help. Appreciate that..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add selenium dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a dependency for org.openqa.selenium
Try adding dependency for org.openqa.selenium in your pom.xml