# Maven, two third parties using incompatible versions of a lib

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a project that using two third party libs. And these two are both using org.eclipse.jetty, but totally different version. The tree is like:

```
[INFO] +- com.some.package:my-core-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.samza:samza-core_2.10:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile
[INFO] |              \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:8.1.8.v20121106:compile - omitted for conflict with 9.2.18.v20160721)
[INFO] \- come:third-party-two:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.18.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

I cannot ask any of these two parties to change their dependencies. Is there a way I could let them use the correct version?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven project depending on two versions of the same artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in Maven you can just have one version of a given dependency. So first of all, you should try to compile and test your program with different versions of jetty (starting from the newer one) to find out whether you find a version that fits all. You can do this by setting the version in the `dependencyManagement` section.

If you do *not* find a compatible version, you get into trouble. You could by some trick try to load both jars, but if they have classes with the same names (which is likely), the class loader can only load one of them. There may be some tools for renaming classes as well, but this may become very messy.