# Maven: how to handle conflicting dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I want (have to) to use two maven dependencies "Y" and "G" next to each other, while they share the same dependency with different versions. 
By default behavior, the older version will be overwritten by the newer one. However this would ruin the performance. 
How can I isolate the two dependencies and make sure they use their proper dependency?

[image]

Comment: `they share the same dependency with different versions` for X?

Comment: Is Y and G running inside an OSGi container? If not than this is not possible...with software I assume you mean a library ?

Comment: @Vishrant as in figure, my project is X, there are two versions of artifact Z in classpath.

Comment: @khmarbaise "with software I assume you mean a library" --> yeah, two maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> By default behavior, the older version will be overwritten by the newer one.

This is not true. By default, Maven uses the *nearest definition* strategy when resolving conflicting versions of the same dependency. It does not necessarily take the new version. This means that the version declared by a POM at a higher level in the dependency tree overrides versions declared in lower level POMs. In case the two versions are on the same level, as is the case in your diagram, the one declared first is taken.

The best way to force a specific version of the dependency is to explicitly define a `dependency` in the parent POM inside a `dependencyManagement` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>groupId-z</groupId>
          <artifactId>dependency-z</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
    ...
```

Then all of the child projects and their dependencies will automatically use the specified version.

For more details on dependency conflict resolution in Maven, see [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that, I DON'T want ALL the dependencies (Here Y and G) use the SAME version of this third library (here Z). Instead I want each to use its proper version.

Comment: This is simply not possible unless you do a workaround. Also it may cause class incompatibility issues if classes share the same package. The closest I can find related is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "X" is one module which has dependencies on both Y and G, then the answer depends on how it is being run. For example: if X is a WAR containing Y and G, then you won't be able to have two different versions of the same dependency or you'll run into class loading issues.

Could you not therefore explicitly declare the correct version for Y and G in their own POMs for when they are used independently, but override it to the necessary shared version when they are being used side by side?