# How to use multiple versions of a third-party library in Java EE project?

Tags: java

I have a Java EE project that needs to use multiple versions of a third-party library, each version in their own JAR file, and each with potentially conflicting classes and tools. What is the best approach to include them in my project?

My thought right now is to write different Web applications and put them in separate WAR files. Each WAR includes utility methods calling each versions of the library. Is it good?

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes I am using Maven.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you need different versions of one library? Wouldn't the latest version of the library have all the necessary functions?

Comment: Have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact)

Comment: @cricket_007 In my particular case, it's because of the legacy code base. Some old but critical components depend on the previous version of the library, while new components need to use the newer version. We cannot upgrade the old components in short time. Hence, this situation, which I am sure is not uncommon. And from my experience, the latest version is not _always_ backward compatible with previous versions, or provides the exact same API.