# picking 2 versions of JAR

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, morphia

My Projects depends on below 2 dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myorg.projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myorg.projectB</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Both of these dependencies are dependant on different versions of `morphia`. When I build my project, only 1 version of morphia is selected. I will need both the `morphia` versions.

Here is what I added based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147660/maven-project-depending-on-two-versions-of-the-same-artifact) solution but this doesn't seem to work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/dep.xml</descriptor>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
                    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
                    <classifier>server</classifier>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
                    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
                    <classifier>server</classifier>
                    <version>0.110</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency/</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

my assembly file `dep.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly>
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                <exclude>**/README*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/dependency</outputDirectory>
    <filtered>false</filtered>
    <includes>
        <include>*.jar</include>
    </includes>
    <fileMode>0600</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

I don't see both the versions of morphia being downloaded or being copied into my `dependency` folder.

Comment: First you are mistaken the goals of the maven-assembly-plugin cause [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html) has only a single goal `single` it has not goal `copy-dependencies`...furthermore if you like to have both versions of the morphia  should be on the classpath? It simply depends on the order on the classpath which is not what you want. You need to make a decision which one will be used...

Comment: What versions of Morphia do you want? Newer versions are backwards compatible with older servers so normally you’d want the very latest Morphia for your project.

Comment: @NicCottrell We are using `morphia-1.3.2` and `morphia-0.110`. Not sure if they are compatible. Even if they are, they have to be compatible with the Mongo driver too. Both the libs connect to different mongos with different driver versions.

Comment: Gosh! 0.110 is more than 2.5 years old. I recommend you migrate away from that and settle on the [active version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.morphia/morphia/1.3.2). What version of MongoDB server are you running?

Comment: @NicCottrell I dont have visibility into what mongodb version we are using. Its an older version but we use `mongo-java-driver-2.14.1` with it, which will not be compatible with `morphia-1.3.2` if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

Maven often finds different versions of artifacts because of transitive dependencies. In that case Maven only picks up the first artifact it encounters.

If you really want to end up with two versions of an artifact you can use plugins like [maven-build-helper-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html). But most probably you won't end up with what you want. To use two different versions of a jar at runtime you'll have to deal with classloaders and that might be really hard to get working. If you really want to go down that path I'll suggest you take a look at osgi and one of it's implementations like [Felix](http://felix.apache.org/).

Comment: I believe, The link I shared had the similar to issue what I am facing. I have found other posts which used `maven-assembly-plugin`. I might be wrong but from the information available it seemed like people have found solutions without playing around with the classloader?