# maven dependency version issues

Tags: java, jar, maven-3

I just got in issue related to Maven and Dependent JAR version. I create following project to analyze issue.

1. I created App_1.jar which is using spring version 4.2.9.
2. I created App_2.jar which is using spring version 4.3.4.
3. I created App_3.jar which is using spring version 4.3.6.
4. I created App_Main.war which will App_1.jar, App_2.jar, App_3.jar.

**According to maven if you use different version it will use the latest one but in my case it using the spring version of jar which i included first which is App_1.jar and its version is 4.2.9.**

Here is the code.

```
**App_1 POM.xml**

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
      <artifactId>App_1</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <name>App_1</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>

**App_2 POM.xml**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
  <artifactId>App_2</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>App_2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

**App_3 POM.xml**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
  <artifactId>App_3</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>App_3</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

App_Main POM.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>App_Main</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>App_Main Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
      <artifactId>App_1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
      <artifactId>App_2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ksh</groupId>
      <artifactId>App_3</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>App_Main</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Maven does not automatically choose the latest version. Where did you read that? It will pick whatever it considers "nearest in the dependency tree": https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html (**Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies.**)

Comment: I read that in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312553/maven-assembly-add-different-version-of-the-same-artifact

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read maven use the latest one?

For transitives dependencies Maven uses a "nearest-wins" strategy to resolves version conflicts, and that means it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies.

[Maven transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)

One possible solution is use the `<dependencyManagement>` to resolve your conflicts.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>spring_context_version_you_want_to_use</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[Maven dependency managament](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

You can check your tree of dependencies with the command:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=your-jar
```

[Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)